# SQL Server - After Insert/ For Insert - Rollback

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below trigger:

```
  CREATE Trigger instructor_expertise on CourseSections
     After Insert
     As Begin
     ......

     If (Not Exists(Select AreaName From AreasOfInstructor Where (InstructorNo = @InstructorNo AND AreaName = @AreaName))) 
     Begin 
     RAISERROR('Course not in instructors expertise', 16, 1)
     rollback transaction  
     End
     GO
```

My question is, does 'rollback transaction' remove the row?
What if it's 'For Insert' instead, does 'rollback transaction' remove the row in that case?

Thanks!!!

Comment: @MitchWheat: a transaction will always exist - no? Either explicit or implicit. And the rollback would terminate that transaction and undo anything that this transaction was attempting to do to the table.

Comment: Yes, sorry Marc, that is correct. I meant an explicit transaction. I think I may have muddied the water... I will delete previous comment.

Comment: Where do you get those values `@InstructorNo` and `@AreaName` from?? Basically, if you do call `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` in your trigger, you will **stop and abort** your `INSERT` and no rows will be inserted at all

Comment: thank u so much marc_s!!! I omitted those codes. both of them are from the 'inserted'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement always runs in a transaction - either you've explicitly defined one, or if not, then SQL Server will use an implicit transaction.

You're inserting one (or multiple) row into your table. Then - still inside the transaction - the `AFTER INSERT` trigger runs and checks certain conditions - typically using the `Inserted` pseudo table available inside the trigger, which contains the rows that have been inserted.

If you call `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` in your trigger, then yes - your transaction, with everything it's been doing, is **rolled back** and it's as if that `INSERT` never happened - nothing shows up in your database table.

Also: `FOR INSERT` is the same as `AFTER INSERT` in SQL Server - the trigger is executed *after* the `INSERT` statement has done its job.

One thing to keep in mind (which a lot of programmers get wrong): the trigger is fired *once per statement* - **NOT** once per row! So if you insert 20 rows at once, the trigger is fired *once* and the `Inserted` pseudo table inside the trigger contains 20 rows. You need to take that into account when writing the trigger - you're **not** always dealing with just a single row being inserted!

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: ok, thanks for that clarification !

Answer (score 0):

no it is not possible because when their is no row exist then it will go in begin block ...

Comment: thanks for the reply! How should I prevent the row to be added then?