# Uniqueidentifier as parameter in SQL Server Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a Function in SQL Server 2012 that I will use in a Check Constraint on a table.
The function works as expected if I do:

```
SELECT [dbo].[CheckValidCardnumberForShellTankingen] ('700678036658047691' ,'2925CA00-6DD5-4F9D-AB0E-AA15DBBD388B')
```

But when I try to set the expression in Check Constraint so:

```
([dbo].[CheckValidCardnumberForShellTankingen]([Volledig kaartnummer],[RollBackCode])=(1))
```

I get a Messaage: `"Error validating constraint 'CK_MyConstraint'"`

I use the Uniqueidentifier in a Where clause and the strange thing is if I replace the parameter with string containing the Uniqueidentifier I dont get this error.

Here is the Function:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Anders Pedersen
-- Create date: 2015-02-13
-- Description: Check of the Cardnumber of a transaction is valid.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckValidCardnumberForShellTankingen]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Cardnumber NvarChar(50),
    @RollBackCode NvarChar(200)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE 
     @Result                BIT
    ,@ResultLenght          BIT
    ,@ResultPrefix          BIT
    ,@CardLenght            INT
    ,@SupplierID            INT
    ,@UseCardnumber         BIT
    ,@Prefix                NvarChar(50)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
     SET @Result                = 0
     SET @ResultLenght          = 0
     SET @ResultPrefix          = 0
     SET @CardLenght            = -1
     SET @SupplierID            = -1
     SET @UseCardnumber         = 0
     SET @Prefix                = ''

    -- Get the UseCardnumber and the SupplierID
    SELECT @UseCardnumber = C.UseCardNumber, @SupplierID = F.SupplierID
    FROM Client C INNER JOIN
        ClientFileUploads F ON C.ClientID = F.ClientID
    WHERE F.RollBackCode = @RollBackCode
    --WHERE F.RollBackCode = '2925CA00-6DD5-4F9D-AB0E-AA15DBBD388B' 

    -- Only carry out the check if the Client use Cards else set the check to True (1)
    IF @UseCardnumber = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @CardLenght =  [CardNumberLenght], @Prefix = ISNULL([Prefix],'') FROM [dbo].[Supplier] AS S WHERE S.SupplierID = @SupplierID

        IF (@CardLenght IS NULL) OR (@CardLenght = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @ResultLenght = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        IF  (LEN(@Cardnumber) - @CardLenght)= 0
            BEGIN
                SET @ResultLenght = 1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @ResultLenght =  0
            END
        END

        IF  SUBSTRING(@Cardnumber, 1, LEN(@Prefix)) = @Prefix
        BEGIN
            SET @ResultPrefix = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ResultPrefix =  0
        END

        IF ((@ResultLenght = 1) AND (@ResultPrefix = 1))
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 0
        END     
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 1
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END

GO
```

Comment: This error is [usually indicative of a typo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the function name looks fine, but are both your column names spelled correctly in the constraint?

Comment: Is the constraint valid? What does `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE [dbo].[CheckValidCardnumberForShellTankingen]([Volledig kaartnummer],[RollBackCode]) = 0` yield, with `mytable` the name of the table you're applying it to?

Comment: @RussellSteen just beat me to suggesting your uniqueidentifier parameters should be typed as such, not as string. Also, UDFs in check constraints are prone to problems. If you need this level of validation a trigger is the way to go.

Comment: @Rhys Jones Indeed I notes that a function for this kind of validation is not the best option. But how do I prevent that the insert/update is done in a trigger if the validation fails?

Comment: You can rollback in triggers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373168/sql-server-after-insert-for-insert-rollback

Comment: If you issue a `ROLLBACK` inside a trigger the DML (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) will not happen. Read up on triggers, start with [CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: I would NOT put a rollback in a trigger. If your calling code has a transaction it will fail when it tries to commit or rollback because the transaction has already been terminated. Leave the RAISERROR in the trigger and let the exception bubble back up.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `[RollBackCode]` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If @RollBackCode is a uniqueidentifier, I recommend making the parameter a uniqueidentifier and not a varchar.

As Rhys Jones points out, you shouldn't use a UDF in a check constraint.

See
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/udf-in-check-constraint-downside

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/078b720f-faac-425c-b51a-33bcecb263d2/check-constraint-with-udf-problem-with-lots-of-data?forum=transactsql

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx

If you need to check in a trigger and roll back -- [SQL Server - After Insert/ For Insert - Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373168/sql-server-after-insert-for-insert-rollback)