# Prevent update if Old and New Column value are Same for a particular Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering table has 100 columns, I would like to prevent update if old value is same as new value efficiently Is this the  Method will have perform benefits as it is taking from the same table which we update?.Any Suggestions?

```
 Update MyTable 
 SET Col1=CASE WHEN mt.Col1 !=mt.Col1 THEN i.Col1 else mt.Col1,
     Col2=CASE WHEN mt.Col2 !=mt.Col2 THEN i.Col2 else mt.Col2,
 .
 .
     Col100 =
 FROM MyTable mt JOIN INSERED i ON mt.id=i.id
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside a trigger or a stored procedure?

Comment: yes inside Trigger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - After Insert/ For Insert - Rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373168/sql-server-after-insert-for-insert-rollback)

Comment: Will the method that i shown above will have any perform benefits as the data is taken from the same table which is getting update

Comment: This is already answered by @marc_s here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374004/13198

Comment: @AsifRahman don't even think of performance yet until you get through the other fundamental stuff.

Comment: Can you suggest a good  Efficient Method for this.Be Specific to my question please

Answer (score 0):

You can use where condition to update only if particular column of both table is not equal.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET mt.Col1 = i.Col1, mt.Col2 = i.Col2, ....
FROM
MyTable mt 
JOIN 
INSERED i 
ON (mt.id=i.id)
WHERE mt.Col1 != i.Col1
```

Comment: Ok that i Understand. My doubt is : Is there is any way to prevent update mt.Col1 when mt.Col1=i.Col1

Comment: Will the method that i shown above will have any perform benefits as the data is taken from the same table which is getting update?

Comment: Can you suggest a good Efficient Method for this.Be Specific to my question please

Answer (score 0):

Considerer using a timesstamp column in both tables indicating the last modification date-time, and change your Update to include it in the where.

Update MyTable 
 mt.Col1 = i.Col1 ,
 mt.Col2 = i.Col2 ,
 .
 .
     Col100 =
 FROM MyTable mt JOIN INSERED i ON mt.id=i.id
where mt.FecMod != i.FecMod