# Check constraint on join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case, check-constraints

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
    id_calendar INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    year int NOT NULL,
    month int NULL,
    day_of_month int NULL,
    day_of_week int NULL,
    week_of_year int NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Param(
    id_param INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    param varchar(30),
    periode varchar(20),
    CONSTRAINT check_periode CHECK (periode IN ('Day','Week','Month','Year'))
);

CREATE TABLE Event (
    id_calendar INT,
    id_param INT
);
```

Whenever a new row is inserted into Event, I want to check that it complies with the parameter's period.

If **periode = 'Day'**, then none of **year,month,day_of_month,day_of_week,week_of_year** should be NULL.

If periode = 'Week', then only day_of_month and day_of_week should be NULL,

...

So I need to join both `FK'S` and build a CHECK constraint from there. Is it possible to pass **id_calendar** and **id_param** to a `UDF` and call it from CHECK ?

For performance reason, I don't want to use a global query, only a check that involves the affected line and its foreign keys.

Comment: You could use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger with a `ROLLBACK` command that you execute if some of your conditions are not met. For more info see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374004/1220550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an entity for `periode` and reference it when relevant. Use composite keys to express "the same `periode`" constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Periodes (
   periode varchar(20),
   CONSTRAINT check_periode CHECK (periode IN ('Day','Week','Month','Year'));
INSERT ...

CREATE TABLE Calendar (
    id_calendar INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    periode varchar(20) not null, -- FK to Periodes.Period 
      -- + check nulls according to period 
      -- + unique (id_calendar,periode) 
    year int NOT NULL,
    month int NULL,
    day_of_month int NULL,
    day_of_week int NULL,
    week_of_year int NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Param(
    id_param INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    param varchar(30),
    periode varchar(20) not null, -- FK to Periodes.Period
    --  + unique(id_param, periode)
);

CREATE TABLE Event (
    id_calendar INT,
    id_param INT,
    periode varchar(20) not null --  + FK(id_calendar, periode) => Calendar(id_calendar, periode)  
      -- + FK(id_param, periode) => Param(id_param, periode)
);
```

Comment: All right, it is a good idea to reference the Period from the Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can define a Function to validate the values and refer it in the CHECK Constraint.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION CheckEvent(@id_Calendar INT, @id_param INT)
    RETURNS BIT
    AS
    BEGIN
    ---LOGIC 
    END
```

Add a check constraint to utilize the function

```
    ALTER TABLE Event ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Event CHECK( dbo.CheckEvent(id_param , id_calendar) = 1)
```